# PostgreSQL: Aggregate by more than one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have the following data format:

```
id       eventtime           use
A    2015-01-01 00:00:00-01    5.2
.
.    2015-06-06 23:59:50-01    5.7  
B 
.
.
```

I'm trying get an output of the form:

```
id        eventtime              use
A         2015-01-01             1200
.         2015-06-06             1400  
.
B         2015-01-01             1500
```

basically sum of the item use for every user for each day in my database.

I tried

```
select id, eventtime, sum(use) from table group by id,eventtime
```

I got an aggregate in this case that I can't really make sense of i.e that it doesn't add up to anything that it should. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert `eventtime` to a date by removing the time component.  I think the simplest way is using `date_trunc()`:

```
select id, date_trunc('day', eventtime) as eventday, sum(use)
from table
group by id, eventday
order by id, eventday;
```

I'm not sure why your sample query has `id` in the `select`, but `user` in the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to `GROUP BY extract('day' FROM eventtime)` or `GROUP BY CAST(eventtime AS date)`.

Note that this will prevent the use of any index on `eventtime`. If you need that you can create an expression index matching what you use in the `group by` clause.